# Getting to Mars requires 12 ISSs of mass w/o tech advances?

Tags: mars, crewed-spaceflight, research

Does anyone have the original source(s) of the following images?
[image]
[image]

I originally found them [here in this Spanish blog](https://www.taringa.net/posts/ciencia-educacion/15907337/Viajar-a-Marte-donde-esta-lo-dificil.html) (translated to [English here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.taringa.net%2Fposts%2Fciencia-educacion%2F15907337%2FViajar-a-Marte-donde-esta-lo-dificil.html&edit-text=&act=url) via Google Translate). Note the captions that state NASA as the source. My primary objective is to find the original or authoritative source — this is for my dissertation research.

No, these images do not appear in DRA 5.0 nor in either of its Addenda. No, Google Image search doesn't find their original sources either.

DRA 5.0 sizes the all chemical propulsion with aerocapture and nuclear thermal propulsion options. All chem was sized to an initial mass at LEO of 1,251.8 metric tons ([DRA 5.0 Table 4-2](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/373665main_NASA-SP-2009-566.pdf) ); NTP was sized to 848.7 metric tons ([DRA 5.0 Table 4-1](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/373665main_NASA-SP-2009-566.pdf)). Assuming the ISS weighs approximately [419.6 tons](https://www.space.com/8876-international-space-station-numbers.html), that means the all chem option weighs almost as much as 3 ISSs; NTP weighs 2 ISSs. With that said, yes, the DRA 5.0 baseline shown in the images check out, thus why I'd like to find the original source. I hope that, by finding the original source(s), I am able to find the data for "DRA 5.0 without the technological advances." The 37 Saturn V launches or 12 ISSs with the current state-of-the-art is a bold claim, so I'd like to see assumptions, analysis, and what went into showing the reduction from 12 to 3 ISSs worth of mass.  Yes, I see that the first image above show the NTP reference architecture — I presume it is an imprecise depiction. And, yes, I can reverse engineer the assumptions of how these techs yield these advances, but I prefer to not do that and cite the original source(s) of the images instead.

Comment: A lot of the other slides in the presentation on the blog are the same as ones used in Stan Love's (non-technical) presentation about the difficulty of getting people to Mars.  I haven't seen this presentation in a few years, maybe there is a technical version of it? I don't expect you to sit through this youtube video (I certainly wouldn't) but maybe it can be a clue to tracking it down. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fturU0u5KJo

Comment: Getting closer... https://www.slideshare.net/Medresearch/nasa-innovation-and-technology-preliminary-planning-nasa, slide 11

Comment: So you're looking for sources that indicate how reducing cryogenic boiloff would save 2000 tonnes of launch mass, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the source.

https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/553607main_APL_Bobby_5_27_11_DW2.pdf, slides 7 and 9.

In case anyone else ever goes looking for the source of these images, I hope this post helps them.

Comment: This would be better editted into the question

Comment: Finding the original source was the answer to the question.  I edited the post to clarify that.